# How do I draw a geofence on a map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, geolocation, geofencing

Does anyone have any good sources for me to read on how to draw a geofence on a map in an iOS app?

I want to learn how to freeze a map on a view and allow a user to draw a square, circle, or polygon to set up a geofence.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 7, a geofence (CLRegion) can only be a circular region.
[CLCircularRegion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLCircularRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you want to draw on a map view, you can add a transparent custom view on top of the map view and handle the touch events on the transparent view.